# Bootstrap navbar turns grey when clicked after applying onclick

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nav

My navbar worked just fine before I added an onclick function.
My onclick function looks like this:

```
$('.nav li a').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'')
        && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var $target = $(this.hash);
        $target = $target.length && $target
            || $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
        if ($target.length) {
            var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
            $('html,body')
                .animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 2000);
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

When I click on one of my items in my navbar it does the onclick function, but when I hover my mouse outside of the navbar item that I just clicked on, it turns grey. When I click on anything after that it removes the grey color again.
My navbar looks like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">

        <a href="#home"><img src="../Images/Logo.png" width=200px" height="50px"/></a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a class="home" href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#projects">My Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The onclick event is adding a focus pseudo class to your li > a element. Until you click away bootstrap is styling the nav item with the following css:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
    color: #333;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

You could overwrite the :focus styling or put this jquery: $(this).blur(); at the end of your function.